# Java Apache POI Tab Stop word document

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a word document that has lines like the following
A name (aligned left) and a price (aligned all the way to the right) both on the same line. I believe this is done by a tab-stop in a word document.  Here is an example, see the first line.
[image]
Is it possible for me to print out into a word document, a line like the first one? I checked around the documentation for apache POI but didn't see anything that allowed you to set a tab stop. However, I wasn't sure if there is another way to get the first line to look like that.

Comment: I don't see any way of doing it with POI. I tried adding it to the template style, but tab stop doesn't seem to work with styles as well.

Answer (score 4):

I used this method to add tabs stops

```
public static void setTabStop(XWPFParagraph oParagraph, STTabJc.Enum oSTTabJc, BigInteger oPos)
{
    CTP oCTP = oParagraph.getCTP();
    CTPPr oPPr = oCTP.getPPr();
    if(oPPr == null)
    {
      oPPr = oCTP.addNewPPr();
    }

    CTTabs oTabs = oPPr.getTabs();
    if(oTabs == null)
    {
      oTabs = oPPr.addNewTabs();
    }

    CTTabStop oTabStop = oTabs.addNewTab();
    oTabStop.setVal(oSTTabJc);
    oTabStop.setPos(oPos);
}
```