# Apache POI - add multiple paragraphs to header/footer on the same line

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I am using Apace POI to process some documents and I would like to add a header/footer which would consist of multiple paragraphs, but I would like for them to be displayed on the same line.

This is my attempt so far:

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

// adding header and footer
CTP ctp = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
CTR ctr = ctp.addNewR();

// create footer components
CTText footerCopyrightText = ctr.addNewT();
footerCopyrightText.setStringValue("\u00A9" + " My Website - " + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));

CTText footerPageText = ctr.addNewT();
footerPageText.setStringValue(document.getProperties().getExtendedProperties().getUnderlyingProperties().getPages() + "");

XWPFParagraph footerCopyrightParagraph = new XWPFParagraph( ctp, document );
footerCopyrightParagraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

XWPFParagraph footerPageParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(ctp, document);
footerPageParagraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);

XWPFParagraph[] footerParagraphs = {footerCopyrightParagraph, footerPageParagraph};
CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = new  XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(document, sectPr );
headerFooterPolicy.createFooter(STHdrFtr.DEFAULT, footerParagraphs);
```

However, the end result so far is that I get a single right-aligned text, which consists of the two XWPFParagraphs, concatenated.

I have also checked some other examples here on Stack Overflow (there was one for a Header, but I didn't manage to get it to work).

A basic idea of what I want to achieve is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkQfB.jpg

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thank you,

Comment: You mean like a table? One left, one center, one right? Maybe a visual sketch of where on a page you want to place what would be helpful

Comment: Yeah, that's the basic idea. Kind of like bootstrap's idea of a row, with text-left, text-center and text-right, but in word.

Comment: By any chance, do you happen to have a code example of what that looks like? Because I am a bit confused as to how this is transposed to Java and Apache POI, since I do not know exactly how to set spacing on a CTText object (if that is what I am supposed to use).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Add Tabstops and use them

Here's my draft - printing my Name Left, Center and Right on a A4 Document. I have no clue whatsoever as to how those position elements are calculated though... Code to add tabstops is from [Java Apache POI Tab Stop word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170704/java-apache-poi-tab-stop-word-document)

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

public class POIExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
            XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();

            XWPFRun tmpRun = paragraph.createRun();
            tmpRun.setText("JAN");
            tmpRun.addTab();
            tmpRun.setText("JAN");
            tmpRun.addTab();
            tmpRun.setText("JAN");

            BigInteger pos1 = BigInteger.valueOf(4500);
            setTabStop(paragraph, STTabJc.Enum.forString("center"), pos1);
            BigInteger pos2 = BigInteger.valueOf(9000);
            setTabStop(paragraph, STTabJc.Enum.forString("right"), pos2);

            File f = File.createTempFile("poi", ".docx");
            try (FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f)) {
                document.write(fo);
            }
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void setTabStop(XWPFParagraph oParagraph, STTabJc.Enum oSTTabJc, BigInteger oPos) {
        CTP oCTP = oParagraph.getCTP();
        CTPPr oPPr = oCTP.getPPr();
        if (oPPr == null) {
            oPPr = oCTP.addNewPPr();
        }

        CTTabs oTabs = oPPr.getTabs();
        if (oTabs == null) {
            oTabs = oPPr.addNewTabs();
        }

        CTTabStop oTabStop = oTabs.addNewTab();
        oTabStop.setVal(oSTTabJc);
        oTabStop.setPos(oPos);
    }
}
```

Comment: While I do need to make some small adjustments, it is working as I would have wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, after some tinkering, I finally have a functioning version. Here's hoping it will prove useful to other users as well.

**Creating footer object code**

```
    // create footer components
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    CTP footerCtp = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
    CTR footerCtr = footerCtp.addNewR();
    XWPFParagraph footerCopyrightParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(footerCtp, document);
    document.getProperties().getExtendedProperties().getUnderlyingProperties().getPages();
    XWPFRun run = footerCopyrightParagraph.getRun(footerCtr);
    run.setText("My Website.com");
    run.addTab();
    run.setText("\u00A9" + " My Website - " + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
    run.addTab();
    run.setText("Right Side Text");

    setTabStop(footerCtp, STTabJc.Enum.forString("right"), BigInteger.valueOf(9000));

    XWPFParagraph[] footerParagraphs = {footerCopyrightParagraph};
    CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
    XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(document, sectPr);
    headerFooterPolicy.createFooter(STHdrFtr.DEFAULT, footerParagraphs);
```

**SetTabStop method**

```
private static void setTabStop(CTP oCTP, STTabJc.Enum oSTTabJc, BigInteger oPos) {
    CTPPr oPPr = oCTP.getPPr();
    if (oPPr == null) {
        oPPr = oCTP.addNewPPr();
    }

    CTTabs oTabs = oPPr.getTabs();
    if (oTabs == null) {
        oTabs = oPPr.addNewTabs();
    }

    CTTabStop oTabStop = oTabs.addNewTab();
    oTabStop.setVal(oSTTabJc);
    oTabStop.setPos(oPos);
}
```